# Using KNSemiModal or MJPopUpView with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Whenever I try and dismiss the semi modal view, I am left with a crashed app. I think I've properly set up the dismiss modal view but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what it looks like in the demo app using XIB files:

```
    MJDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
```

Here's what I am trying to replace it with:

```
[self presentPopupViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewCOntrollerWithIdentifier:@"example"]  animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
```

The `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSString]` doesn't seem to be replacing the `instWithNib` (or whatever function that is) properly.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.

I would just delete all the init methods in MJDetailViewController and also added "example" in the   'Storyboard ID' attribute of identity inspector then called

```
[self presentPopupViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewCOntrollerWithIdentifier:@"example"]  animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
```